# Fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04 - Won't connect to wireless

Tags: wireless, 15.04, internet, connection, iwlwifi

I have just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop, however I cannot connect to my wifi. My network shows up fine, but when I try to connect it simply waits a minute trying to connect and then shows a message saying 'You have been disconnected'. Is there an easy fix for this? My wireless card is Realtek, I believe. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: The following results from running the command "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
" in terminal

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b4] (rev 93)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8270]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thank you, I have updated the original post with the requested output.

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

and reboot.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this when I finish up with classes later today. One thing I did just notice is that it will connect fine to my University's guest Wifi (which requires no password).

Comment: Also check that you have AES encryption in your router, not TKIP.

Comment: I just double checked and my router is using only AES encryption. I also ran the line you gave me and rebooted, but it did not seem to fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: I just tried disabling the password on my home network and connecting again, but it didn't fix anything, so it doesn't seem to particularly be tied to just networks with passwords.